# HTTPS jquery Signalr client not able to access HTTP SignalR hub?

Tags: jquery, signalr, signalr.client

Same set of codes work will when HTTP client access it.

My Hub code:

```
[HubName("MyHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    private readonly IHubContext _hubContext;
    public MyHub()
    {
        _hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    }
    public void SendMessage()
    {
        Clients.All.ChangeStatus(true);
    }
    public void CheckConnectionStatus(string str)
    {
        Clients.All.ChangeStatus(false);
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        SendMessage();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

}

Client:

```
var hub;
var url = 'http://localhost:44317/signalr';   
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.url = url;
var hub = $.connection.MyHub;
hub.client.ChangeStatus = function (status) {
    alert('new Status' + status);
};
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        alert('Now connected');
        hub.invoke('CheckConnectionStatus', '1');
    })
    .fail(function () { alert('Could not Connect!'); });
```

When trying HTTPS client i get error message.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/SignalRClientApp/Home/Index' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://localhost:44317/signalr/hubs'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
>
> Index:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined(…)

Comment: Do you change the `url` at client when you run you server as HTTPS ?

Comment: No, We didnt change the url when running in client

Comment: Well that is the problem, isn't it? The `url` is still pointing to an HTTP resource while it should be pointing to an HTTPS resource